# Show that $\frac{\Gamma(1 + x)}{\Gamma(1 + x + n)} \leq \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)}$ for $x \in (0,1), n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, factorial, gamma-function

> Show that $\frac{\Gamma(1 + x)}{\Gamma(1 + x + n)} \leq \frac{1}{\Gamma(n+1)}$ for $x \in (0,1), n \in \mathbb{N}$

Here $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). This inequality is handy as $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ which is a more elementary function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use
$$\Gamma(y+1)=y\Gamma(y)$$
to establish
$$\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+x+n)}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+n)}.$$
What happens when $x=0$?

Comment: Thanks, I like it when people give a hint rather than a worked out answer, keep it going! :)